# How to use xindy with XeTeX/LuaTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex, indexing, unicode, xindy

According to [Xindy revisited: Multi-lingual index creation for the UTF-8 age (TUGboat)](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-3/tb93schrod.pdf), “if one has a raw index file that was produced by [XeTeX], one can use xindy; it will ‘just work’.”

Unfortunately I can't get it to “just work”. How can I use Xindy together with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

---

An example LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
start
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{ü}
end
\end{document}
```

The LaTeX Companion (2ed) then tells me to run

```
texindy -L german-duden test.idx
```

However when I do this all umlauts are sorted under O.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on Ulrike's answer, here is one way to invoke `xindy` to get it to sort `.idx` files created by Xe/LuaLaTeX. The trick is to use `xindy` directly (instead of `texindy`) and pass the `-C utf8` flag.

*Minimal Example*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
üäö

start 
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{ü}
end

\printindex
\end{document}
```

*Compilation*

```
lualatex filename.tex
xindy -M texindy -C utf8 -L german-duden filename.idx 
lualatex filename.tex
```

---

In `(pdf)latex` you can use UTF-8 encoding and xindy in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
start
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{ü}
end
\printindex
\end{document}
```

And then simply run `texindy -L ⟨language⟩ ⟨filename⟩.idx`.

In LuaTeX you can also use the `luainputenc` package to use legacy encodings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
start 
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{ü}
end
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Again, run `texindy -L ⟨language⟩ ⟨filename⟩.idx`.

Here the result for both examples:

[image: result]

Comment: As I said, I want to compile with XeTeX or LuaTeX. Both of those provide UTF-8 by default and don't use any `inputenc`/`fontenc` ”hacks” to support the encoding. So this won't work.

Comment: The problem here is, that the `.idx` file created by `pdflatex` isn't actual unicode, but contains LaTeX-encoded umlauts (etc.). In comparison the modern engines create fully unicode-encoded `.idx` files. `xindy` is supposed to support this, I just don't know how.

Comment: I does work with the `luainputenc` hack. Still I'd prefer a solution that uses Unicode throughout. While the solution works in this case, something like `\index{α}` would still cause trouble.

Comment: @Caramdir: I saw it. I tried also `fontspec` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Surprisingly `fontspec` and `luainputenc` seem to work together for me .

Comment: @Caramdir: I changed my example according to your comment.

Comment: @Caramdir: It is not surprising that fontspec + luainputenc works: fontspec loads xunicode which gives most of the standard commands (\" etc) senseful definitions. But having to use luainputenc should not be necessary. After all one point of xindy is to get real utf8 support.

Comment: That last example finally does what I want. Thank you and @Ulrike. Before posting this question I even tried `texindy -C utf8`, but this gives an error. Apparently it does work when using `xindy` directly. Could you please edit your answer to make it clearer that the first way is the correct one and the other options should only be used in legacy documents (or when working with `(pdf)latex`).

Comment: I changed your answer a bit, so that it is more helpful for people coming here from google who didn't follow how the answer came to be (this question is currently the top result for a search for `lualatex xindy`).

Comment: @Caramdir: No problem ;-)

Comment: @Caramdir @Marco: Hi, I tried your solution (i.e. running `xindy -M texindy  -C utf8 am.idx`) but it doesn’t work. I get this error: `*** - PROGN: variable TEXINDY.XDY has no value`. Can someone tell whats wrong.

Comment: @Tobi: You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @Caramdir: Wasn’t sure about that, but while preparing that question I found the solution. I’ll posted it as a self-anwser: [Using windy with texindy.xdy](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185253/4918).

Answer (score 6):

here is an example with an own style file for `xindy`. Run it with

```
lualatex <file>
xindy -C utf8 -I latex -M myModuleE <file>.idx
lualatex <file>
```

then I get the attached output

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents,multicol}
\begin{filecontents*}{myModuleE.xdy}
(define-attributes ("default"))
(define-location-class "page-numbers" ("arabic-numbers"))
(markup-index :open  "~n\begin{theindex}~n"
              :close "~n\end{theindex}~n"
              :tree)
(markup-locclass-list :open "\quad{}")
(markup-locref-list   :sep ", ")
(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \item "           :depth 0)
( define-letter-group "A--D" :prefixes ("A" "B" "C" "D") )
( define-letter-group "E--G" :after "A--D" :prefixes ("E" "F" "G") )
( define-letter-group "H--K" :after "E--G" :prefixes ("H" "I" "J" "K") )
( define-letter-group "L--N" :after "H--K" :prefixes ("L" "M" "N" ) )
( define-letter-group "O--R" :after "L--N" :prefixes ("O" "P" "Q" "R") )
( define-letter-group "S--V" :after "O--R" :prefixes ("S" "T" "U" "V") )
( define-letter-group "W--Z" :after "S--V" :prefixes ("W" "X" "Y" "Z") )
(sort-rule "a" "A")
(sort-rule "b" "B")
(sort-rule "c" "C")
(sort-rule "d" "D")
(sort-rule "e" "E")
(sort-rule "f" "F")
(sort-rule "g" "G")
(sort-rule "h" "H")
(sort-rule "i" "I")
(sort-rule "j" "J")
(sort-rule "k" "K")
(sort-rule "l" "L")
(sort-rule "m" "M")
(sort-rule "n" "N")
(sort-rule "o" "O")
(sort-rule "p" "P")
(sort-rule "q" "Q")
(sort-rule "r" "R")
(sort-rule "s" "S")
(sort-rule "t" "T")
(sort-rule "u" "U")
(sort-rule "v" "V")
(sort-rule "w" "W")
(sort-rule "x" "X")
(sort-rule "y" "Y")
(sort-rule "z" "Z")
(markup-letter-group-list :sep "~n\indexspace")
(sort-rule "Ä" "A")
(sort-rule "ä" "A")
(sort-rule "Ö" "O")
(sort-rule "ö" "O")
(sort-rule "Ü" "U")
(sort-rule "ü" "U")
(merge-rule "\\[a-zA-Z@]+ *" "" :eregexp)
(merge-rule "\\[^a-zA-Z@]" "" :eregexp)
(merge-rule "^[{}$]" "" :eregexp)
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
  {\raggedright\small\let\item\@idxitem \parskip .0pt\@plus .3\p@\relax
   \begin{multicols}{2}}{\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
% xindy -C utf8 -I latex -M myModuleE datei.idx
\begin{document}
\printindex     \newpage  foo \index{ä}\index{ü}
\index{Aal}   \index{Berg}\index{Cäsar}
\index{Donau} \index{Emil}\index{Flora}
\index{Garten}\index{Ober}\index{Zucker}
\index{Österreich}\index{klein}\index{groß}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a working xindy. But according to this message http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=26841124 I think you need at least the option -C utf8 and perhaps also a new xindy style.