# Xindy with XeLaTeX gives error message

Tags: indexing, xindy

I would like to run XeLaTeX with Xindy. Therefore I copied the example in question [How to use xindy with XeTeX/LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25623). I used the code from where this is written ([Herbert’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25777)), but I used XeLaTeX instead:

```
xelatex <file>
xindy -C utf8 -I latex -M myModuleE <file>.idx
xelatex <file>
```

Using these command codes I get:

> ```
> Unsupported input markup latex.
> ```

When I remove `-I latex` I get the following error message. Unfortunately I do not get Xindy running anD I get an error message:

> ```
> *** - PROGN: variable MYMODULEE.XDY has no value
> ```

The module "MYMODULEE.XDY" is created and is in the directory of the TeX project.
When I tried different other approaches (including different codes) always this error message appears, even though the relevant `*.xdy` is present and not empty.

Has anyone an idea what goes wrong?

I use a Windows 7 computer with the newest version of TeXworks, and a MacBook with Mac OS X 10.9.1 and TeXworks for mac.

I never before used Xindy, so  think it is still a configuration problem. So far I used LaTeX and MakeIndex, but u have many international characters, that is the reason why I would like to switch.

Comment: BTW: why does your title mention `xelatex` when your example is using `lualatex`?

Comment: Do you use TeX Live in also in Windows? MacOS X is a Unix derivate, and therefore the lettercase does matter. So, there is a difference between `MyModuleE` and `MYMODULEE`. On the other hand I wonder why here a variable should be involved.

Comment: Not to forget tis one: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Yes you are right. I did copy the code from the example on this page. but i used xelatex instead of lulatex.

Comment: @Chris: You can always edit your own questions (and answers), also with your low reputation. This time I changed it for you.

Comment: BTW I forgot to mention: I must confirm the issue. It disappears, if I use `texindy`, as written by Herbert, or – not surprisingly then – add a second module call with `-M texindy`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex
\def\Index#1{#1\index{#1}}
\begin{document}
\Index{foo} \Index{bar}
\newpage \Index{baz}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

run

```
xelatex <file>
texindy <file>.idx
xelatex <file>
```

will produce:

[image]

The example which you mentioned, can be run with

```
texindy -C utf8 -I omega -M myModuleE <file>.idx
```

and an additional `\let\lettergroup\textbf` in the preamble of your document

Comment: What is now different to the other (older) answer? Could you, please, add here some remarks or update your old answer? Is it really an issue LuaLaTeX vs. XeLaTeX? I also wonder why now `omega` should be used and not `latex`. In a test the difference whether error or not was only xindy vs. texindy (or xindy + module texindy) – after letting `\lettergroup` to `\textbf`.

Comment: Using xelatex, imakeidx (instead of makeidx) and xindy, I had similar problems, [cf. this Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168873/xelatex-xindy-imakeidx-could-not-find-file-tex-inputenc-utf8-xdy). I get an error message when I try to run texindy from imakeidx together with the `-C utf8` option. But I need to call `-M texindy.xdy`, or include `(require "texindy.xdy")` in my xindy style file. I don't use the `-I` option at all.