# XeLaTeX, xindy, imakeidx "Could not find file "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy"

Tags: xetex, unicode, xindy, imakeidx

I'm trying to use XeLaTeX, imakeidx and xindy for a german book with multiple indexes.
Based on an answer on [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25623/how-to-use-xindy-with-xetex-luatex), (which works) I tried to switch to xelatex and imakeidx. Calling

```
xelatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

on this file test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-M texindy -L german-duden -C utf8]
\begin{document}
üäö
start 
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{ü}\index{ÖÖ}
end
\printindex
\end{document}
```

gives me the error message:

> (require "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy")
>   ERROR: Could not find file "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy" !

Leaving out xindy option "-C utf8" gives me an index with alll umlauts sorted under "O".

I just discovered that xindy does work when run separately, without being started from within xelatex per imakeidx, but from the command prompt:

```
 $ xindy -M texindy -C utf8 -L german-duden test.idx
```

No nagging and no mention of "utf8.xdy" either.

Comment: imakeidx calls texindy and not xindy and texindy doesn't work with -C utf8. Add  `\makeatletter
\def\imki@progdefault{xindy}
\makeatother` after loading imakeidx.

Comment: Yes, that's it. And don't use `\makeindex[program=xindy ...]` either. Thanks @Ulrike!

Comment: @user42591 I'll correct the bug with `truexindy` as soon as possible. But `\makeindex[program=truexindy]` should work.

Comment: I just found out that TeXworks (i.e.: I ;) ) was using an old TeXLive installation. With TeXLive 2013, `\makeindex[program=truexindy]` works.

Comment: @egreg Wanna write something up that can be considered an answer? :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Done

Answer (score 3):

Calling `\makeindex[program=truexindy,...]` works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=truexindy,options=-M texindy -L german-duden -C utf8]
\begin{document}
üäö
start
\index{a}\index{b}\index{ä}\index{ü}\index{ÖÖ}
end
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]