# Using xindy with texindy.xdy

Tags: xetex, xindy

This is a follow up on [How to use xindy with XeTeX/LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25623/4918).

When I use this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Umlaut Ä\index{Ä}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

with this commands

```
xelatex file.tex
xindy -M texindy -C utf8 file.idx
xelatex file.tex
```

the use of `xindy` shows this error:

```
*** - PROGN: variable TEXINDY.XDY has no value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the `-L` option isn’t optional when using `-M texindy`, so I had to use

```
xindy -C utf8 -M texindy -L german-duden file.idx
```

to make it work.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to add `-L german-duden` and `-C utf8` to my own style file to shorten the command to `xindy -M mystyle file.idx`.